# How to make a sphere half shape in Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a question with sphere modeling in Unity. I want to make my sphere half shape. So how to do this?

[image: print screen]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should create 3D model of half shape and put it in unity editor. Then put your model in scene.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Blender or SketchUp, Both free programs but i recommend Blender.